# Change default media player on Ubuntu Mate Indicator Applet Complete

Tags: indicator-sound, mate-panel

Little help.

Where on Ubuntu Mate do you set the default app that displays on the "Indicator Applet Complete" when you click the speaker/sound icon?

I have checked many settings and options. They are all set to Rhythmbox.

But Firefox is set and I have yet to figure out how to change that.

[image]

Comment: What do you have in Prefered Applications in the Control Senter?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu MATE version? If I understand correctly and from my experience - this menu is provided by `indicator-sound` and provides a list of MPRIS-capable media players, which are controlled by *org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer* or *org.mpris.MediaPlayer2* Dbus-interface; thus `indicator-sound` shows last used media player. In your case Firefox [seems](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/widget/gtk/MPRISServiceHandler.h#L19) to be last used media-player. So you have to try opening other mediaplayer and playing some media in it to make it last used.

Comment: Thank you both for the assist.

Ubunutu Mate 20.04

Yes, Rhythmbox is set as the Preferred Application for "Multimedia Player".

Yep. The last player gets the focus+controls on the sound indicator.

But it was not working for Rhythmbox.

See my posted answer below.

The fix was to remove+purge and reinstalled Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty then!

Thank you both for the assist.

Ubunutu Mate 20.04

Yes, Rhythmbox is set as the Preferred Application for "Multimedia Player".

Yep. The last player gets the focus+controls on the sound indicator.

But it was not working for Rhythmbox.

If I run VLC, it gets the focus+controls. If I then open an MP3 in Firefox, it returns to Firefox (last one used).

I removed/purged and reinstalled Rhythmbox. Now it works again. It now gets the focus+controls on the sound indicator.

One odd item, Rhythmbox installs two items that can be selected...

rhythmbox.desktop

rhythmbox-device.desktop

I changed the X-GNOME-FullName to "Rhythmbox Music Player (Device)" to differentiate it. If I select if for the default or preferred, it does not work as expected.

If I use rhythmbox-device, it opens Rhythmbox, but does not play the selected MP3.

I also found the d-conf settings... (these two do not exist on my system: org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer or org.mpris.MediaPlayer2)

.org.canonical.indicator.sound.interested-media-players (these show on the sound indicator).

['firefox.desktop', 'vlc.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop']

com.canonical.indicator.sound.preferred-media-players

[rhythmbox.desktop']

Again, thanks for the assist.

The fix was to remove+purge and reinstalled Rhythmbox.

Peace.

--RayJ